# Keep getting the same error while trying to use Mongoose in a NestJS project

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I get the following error:

```
node_modules/mongoose/index.d.ts:1:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: DocumentDefinition, FilterQuery, UpdateQuery, NativeError, Mongoose, SchemaTypes, STATES, connection, connections, models, mongo, version, CastError, ConnectionOptions, Collection, Connection, disconnected, connected, connecting, disconnecting, uninitialized, Error, QueryCursor, VirtualType, Schema, SchemaDefinition, SchemaTypeOpts, Subdocument, Array, DocumentArray, Buffer, ObjectId, ObjectIdConstructor, Decimal128, Map, Query, mquery, Aggregate, SchemaType, Promise, PromiseProvider, Model, Document, ModelUpdateOptions
```

So far I've tried deleting all of my node_modules folder, npm install again and i also tried doing
rm -rf node_modules
npm install -g npm@latest
npm i core-util-is

And so far the same error apears, I'm really confused of whats wrong here.

Comment: If you're using `@nestjs/mongoose`, are you also using `@types/mongoose`?

Comment: Yeah I think that was the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@nestjs/mongoose@7.2.3` uses `mongoose@5.11.17`. `mongoose@5.11.0` introduced its own types and broke all integrations using `@types/mongoose`. Looks like you need to remove `@types/mongoose` and update the typings in your project to align with `mongoose@5.11.0`

Comment: That is a lot of project to refactor

Comment: The other option is to drop down the version of `@nestjs/mongoose` to `~7.1.0` and make sure to use `mongoose` `~5.10.0`

Comment: @nestjs/mongoose 7.0.2 with mongoose 5.10.13 should work, make sure to remove the "^" in order to avoid updates.

Comment: Yup! This was the solution!